# How to create a session for a visitor?

Tags: laravel

I am creating a simple web shop page, and I don't want visitors to register. So when they put articles in a cart, how can i remember their orders and store them in the database?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to store guests-relatives in a DB since we don't know who they are (no ID, no username, etc).

Why don't you use [sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session) to save guests cart? I think a lot of webshop use this system.

Answer (score 0):

you can use session to handle this part specially session id which related to visitors in php you can do it like this

```
<?php    
session_start();    
echo session_id();
?>
```

in laravel 5.5 just 2 steps 
in your controller write this code

```
use Session;
```

and inside your controller function write the following code

```
session()->getid();
```

and if you need to deal with it inside your blade view just write the following code

```
{{session()->getid()}}
```